# format input value as you type

Tags: vue.js

I have a couple of inputs in which I can enter an amount, I am trying to write in the inputs to format the amount and add the points(.) of thousands, millions, etc.

The value that is written in the input is saved in an object to send it later. It had a function that did this, but when formatting the amount, the value was formatted the same way adding the points.

How can I format only when writing the amount in the input and it is formatted, but the value remains the same?

These are the inputs that I want to format when writing:

```
<div class="budget info" :class="{ 'input-error' : inputsValid.budget }">
  <label>Budget</label>
  <input 
    type="number" 
    v-model="info.budget"
    @input="() => { info.dealbudget === '' ? inputsValid.budget = true : inputsValid.budget = false }"
  >
</div>

<div class="area info" :class="{ 'input-error': inputsValid.area }">
  <label>Area</label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    v-model="info.area"
    @input="() => { info.superficie === '' ? inputsValid.area= true : inputsValid.area= false }">
</div>
```

object where I store the value:

```
const info = ref({
  budget: '',
  area: '',
})
```

I am dealing with a computed one, I think that is the way to do it, when loading it formats the amount ($0.00) well, when writing it does not:

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency', 
  currency: 'USD'
})

const format = computed(() => {
   return formatter.format(info.value.dudget)
})
```

Comment: Could you give some examples, so I could understand it better? Show some code you already have

Comment: You may find useful this component https://github.com/coders-tm/vue-number-format

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a special library to solve this problem in Vue 3. You can use Regex and Intl.NumberFormat from native JavaScript inside a function to filter string from the input field. Then, trigger it using @input.

Tag HTML:

```
<input ref="inputForm" @input="formatCurrency()" :value="inputFormatted" type="text">
```

Script:

```
const inputForm = ref(null)
const inputFormatted = ref(null)

const formatCurrency = () => {
    const locale = "id-ID" // your local formatting
    const currency = "IDR" // your currency
    const input = inputForm.value
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { style: "currency", currency: currency})
    const digits = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { useGrouping: false, }).format(-1234567809)
    const notDigit = new RegExp("[^" + digits + "]+", "ug")
    const comma = notDigit.exec( new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, { useGrouping: false }).format(1.5))[0]
    const notDigitOrComma = new RegExp( "[^" + digits + comma + "]+", "ug")

    const val = input.value
    const cursor = input.selectionStart
    const numsToCursor = val.slice(0, cursor).replace(notDigit, "").length
    const afterSign = notDigit.test(val.slice(cursor - 2, cursor - 1))
    const newVal = formatter.format(val.replace(notDigitOrComma, "").replace(comma, "."))
    const reCursor = new RegExp(
        "^(?:[^" +
            digits +
            "]*[" +
            digits +
            "]){" +
            numsToCursor +
            "}" +
            (afterSign ? "[^" + digits + "]*" : ""),
        "ug"
    );

    input.value = newVal;
    reCursor.exec(newVal);
    input.selectionStart = reCursor.lastIndex;
    input.selectionEnd = reCursor.lastIndex;
    inputFormatted.value = newVal
}
```